# How to detect a typo in a product search and suggest possible corrections?

Tags: algorithm, validation, search, user-interface, data-entry

Given a very large database of product names, how would you detect possible typos in user searches and suggest possible corrections (Kinda like the way Google presents them)?

E.g.

User enters "fork handels" and presses 'search'.

They get back

"No results. Did you mean 'fork handles'?"

Comment: I did type that at first, but thought it might have obscured the question a bit :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several approaches for this problem:

1. Keeping a table of **most popular misspellings** in your database. If you need some common misspellings: [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Lists_of_common_misspellings/For_machines))
2. Using an algorithm based on the **[edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)**: In information theory and computer science, the edit distance between two strings of characters is the number of operations required to transform one of them into the other. There are several different algorithms to define or calculate this metric. Read the [Wikipedia article for the Levenshtein algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for example.
3. If you are using Lucene for full text search, [here is a nice article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/08/09/didyoumean.html?page=2) which shows how to implement the "Did you mean" feature.
4. If you see that feature as simple spell-correction, here are some nice, very short implementations in several languages: [How to Write a Spelling Corrector](http://www.norvig.com/spell-correct.html)

Comment: Since link in point 3 is dead, just in case somebody wants to refer,it  is present in [Oracle Community Archive](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983151) OR you can look it in [WayBackMachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20051029074946/http://today.java.net:80/pub/a/today/2005/08/09/didyoumean.html)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [phonetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm), such as [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) to find matches that sound similar.

PostgreSQL has a module named [fuzzystrmatch](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html), with the docs showing examples of using Soundex, Levenshtein, Metaphone, and Double Metaphone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure I read that google keeps a list of what a user retypes when they get no results.  You could keep a mapping of these values (say if the retyped string begins with the same letter).

Comment: That is a good idea, though I suspect that it may work for Google thanks in part by the sheer unimaginable volume of requests that they process. A lower-traffic site may struggle to build a useful-sized database.